# Explode by comma and new line together

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a basic textarea. When user enter some text I explode words by comma ",". Now I also want to seperate words by new line. How can I do it.

This is my code part that explodes words by comma.

```
if(isset($_POST["btn"])){
    $words     = $_POST["inp_text"];
    $words_arr = explode(",",$words);

    foreach($words_arr as $word){
        echo $word."<br>";
    }
}
```

How can I add new line functionality to this code part. I think, I should generate a string from `$word` in loop than after loop I should explode this string by new line again.

Is there a better idea?

For better understading I add some examples.

input:

```
apple, melon, a, b, c
```

output:

```
apple melon a b c
```

input (with new line)

```
x,y,z,a
b
c
```

output:

```
x y z a b c
```

Comment: why don't Use  preg_split. much better. time and coding both are saved.

Comment: try $words_arr  = preg_split('/[\\n\,]+/', $words);

Comment: Based on the answers I think there is quite a lot of confusion if you want an array or a string as the output. Your question title suggests array while your example output suggests string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$split_strings = preg_split('/[\ \n\,]+/', $your_string);
```

Comment: This answ\er u\ses unne\cessar\y es\c\a\ping in the character class.  (and is a code-only answer hence it is low-value).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_split` in order to split your string into words, no matter is there is a comma or a new line.

```
$wordsArray = preg_split('/\W/', $yourString, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$output = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $input);
?>
```

`\n` is a newline, you replace it with a normal space. Definetly no need for complicated regex here!:)

Comment: but if I do that my array still has not splitted words (elements) by new line. It only deletes \n after words. Am I wrong?

Comment: Don't get you sorry, this removes ALL new lines in your $input string

Comment: @hakkikonu Oh yeah, sorry, of course u have to give str_replace an array, fixed! (Code was untested)

Answer (score -4):

You could split the input by lines, then for each line, split the line by words.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btn"])){
    $data = $_POST["inp_text"];
    $lines = explode("\n", $data);

    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $words = explode(' ', $lines);
        foreach($words as $word)
        {
            echo $word.' ';
        }
    }
}
```